# Is there a way of aggregating rows without summing up their results?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions, pyodbc, categorization

My DataFrame consists of 2 columns. One with a patient's id and one with a patient's problem.
I need to create a DataFrame in which all problems of a patient are in one row with the corresponding patient's ID. For now if a patient has a problem  this dataframe makes a unique row.

```
PAT_MRN_ID  Problem                      
9641956     Headache
9641956     Stomach_ache  
8227510     Headache 
8165474     Chicken_pox
7860000     Stomach_ache
```

The above example needs to like:

```
 PAT_MRN_ID  Headache         Stomach_ache      Chicken_pox
 9641956      1                1                   0
 8227510      1                0                   0
 8165474      0                0                   1
 7860000      0                1                   0
```

Ultimately I want to categorize the DataFrame to the above example. I tried using loops and aggregating, but unfortunately my basic programming skills were not enough.

Answer (score 2):

Use pd.get_dummies.

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"PAT_MRN_ID": [9641956, 9641956, 8227510, 8165474, 7860000], "Problem": ["Head", "Stomach", "Head", "Pox", "Stomach"]})
pd.get_dummies(df,columns=["Problem"]).groupby(df.index).sum()
```

```
                  Problem_Head  Problem_Pox  Problem_Stomach
PAT_MRN_ID                                            
7860000                0            0                1
8165474                0            1                0
8227510                1            0                0
9641956                1            0                1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), max per index and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('PAT_MRN_ID')['Problem'], 
                    prefix='', prefix_sep='')
         .max(axis=0, level=0)
         .reset_index())
print (df)

PAT_MRN_ID Chicken_pox  Headache  Stomach_ache                                  
9641956               0         1             1
8227510               0         1             0
8165474               1         0             0
7860000               0         0             1
```

Answer (score 0):

First get dummies for 'Problem' and then group

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ "PAT_MRN_ID" : [9641956,9641956,8227510,8165474,7860000],
                    "Problem" : ["Headache","Stomach-Ache","Headache","Chicken-Pox","Stomach-Ache"]
                 })

    PAT_MRN_ID  Problem
0   9641956     Headache
1   9641956     Stomach-Ache
2   8227510     Headache
3   8165474     Chicken-Pox
4   7860000     Stomach-Ache


df=pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Problem'],prefix='',prefix_sep='')
     .groupby(['PAT_MRN_ID'], as_index=False)
     .max()


    PAT_MRN_ID  Chicken-Pox Headache    Stomach-Ache
0   7860000     0           0           1
1   8165474     1           0           0
2   8227510     0           1           0
3   9641956     0           1           1
```